# Using a numerical solver to solve a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, homework

> Consider the competition model defined by
>
> dx/dt = x (2 − 0.4 x − 0.3 y)
> dy/dt = y (1 − 0.1 y − 0.3 x)
>
> Where the population x(t) and y(t) are measured in the thousands and t in years. Use a numerical solver to analyze the populations over a long period of time for
>
> 1. x(0) = 1.5, y(0) = 3.5

I have used [the documentation of NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html), but I was not able to make it work. Can you supply code for solving the above system with the initial values I give? If I had example code for solving this first initial value problem, I think I could handle the other 14 initial values I have for the same equation. I only need to know how to code the equation system like this:

```
sol1 = DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] - Cos[Pi x / 2], y[2] == 2}, y[x], x];
```

It's my first time using this software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I solve a system of differential equation using NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181856/how-can-i-solve-a-system-of-differential-equation-using-ndsolve)

Comment: Before you ask other people to do your homework for you, I think you should read [this documentation article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalSolutionOfDifferentialEquations.html)

Comment: Use this syntax. `NDSolve[{Eq1,Eq2,ic1,ic2},{depvar1,depvar2},{t,0,10}]`

Comment: The ODE in the code you show is not at all like system in the problem statement. Therefore, the example code is  no help in clarifying your question. Also, the problem statement directs  you to use a numerical solver. In Mathematica that would be `NDSolve`.